# Adapt the Angular Material input field to screen width

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to make a two equal column grid with CSS grid system. In each of the columns I want to put an input field that takes the 100% of the column's width.
To achieve this I have this html:

```
<div class="grid">

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Title">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Title">
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 2em;
}
```

The result in fullscreen is fine but when I decrease browser window width the input field on the right goes outside of the container.

Images attached with the exposed behaviour.

[image: Full screen]

[image: Resized]

Comment: Have you tried `display: flex` and adding `fxFill` to element?  Post a stackblitz or plunkr?  https://github.com/angular/flex-layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to add a `width: 100%` to the `mat-form-field`?

If it's not working, try to use angular flex layout to use css flexbox in your angular projet.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the desired result I enclose both of the input fields inside a `<div>` with the next CSS class:

```
.mainContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And then apply to each field this properties:

```
.mainContainer > * {
    flex: 1;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```